# React setState race conditions

Tags: reactjs

I am building a React component that does a lot of calls in the background to gather data.
I want the View to be as responsive as possible, loading in data as soon as we get it. However, this is causing race conditions in handling the state properly.

Occasionally one experiment result unsets another. 
How do I handle this parallelism properly?

```
const ctrl = this;
this.state.experiments.foreach((experiment) => {
    this.props.ReportV4.kpi({
        experimentId: experiment.id
    }).then(function (report) {
        experiment.kpi.significant = report.significanceReached;
        experiment.kpi.uplift = report.uplift || "N/A";

        ctrl.setState({
            experiments: update(ctrl.state.experiments, {[experiment.key]: {$set: experiment}})
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is how JavaScript as a single threaded language maintains its callback stack. Your loop will create certain callbacks in stack. I would like to recommend, you maintain an `experiments` object as a class property. This will contain all callback data upon receiving.

in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.experiment= {};
}
```

in promise callback:

```
// populate your experiment whit significant & uplift etc.

this.experiments[experiment.key] = experiment;

this.setState({
    experiments: this.experiments
});
```

You can render these experiments with their key names without even iterating over experiments.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Your solution is also a great one, perhaps better as it is somewhat simpler.